# Laravel : sync ids issue

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, synchronization

Laravel in [many to many sync section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) has an example:

> You may also pass additional intermediate table values with the IDs:

```
$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);
```

lets say we have this array retrived from user selected roles:

```
[2,3,1 => ['expires' => true]]
```

but this array will not remain like this.in fact both `3` and `1=> ..` has the array **key** equivalent to `1` .so the `3` will be overridden .at the end this array will be turned to :

```
 [2,1 => ['expires' => true]] //array value 3 is removed
```

how may i solve this issue as i have no control over roles ids order?

Answer (score 0):

Use `syncWithoutDetaching` or `sync($ids, false)` for your issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.php#L70